# print something when there is a None

Tags: python

I would like to print None but somehow it did not enter the loop I prepared.

My code:

New Update:

```
    a = [{"king":[{"tok":"many", "quite":"forget"}],"man":"one"},{"man":"one"},{"man":"onee"}, {"king":[{"tok":"sin"}]},{"king":[{"tok":"kingkong"}]}]
aa = ["many", "yet", "sin"]
for xx in aa:
    for x in a:
        exists = x.get('king', [])
        if exists:
            for e in exists:
                if xx == e["tok"]:
                    print(xx)
                else:
                    print("wrong")
        else:
            print("empty")
```

My current output:

```
many
empty
empty
wrong
wrong
wrong
empty
empty
wrong
wrong
wrong
empty
empty
sin
wrong
```

Expected output:

```
many
empty
empty
sin
wrong
```

I dont know why it looped so many times and didnt print the expected output

Comment: `[] is None` will always be false

Comment: Is there a way to enter that function too because I wanted to print("this part this None") for the dictionary without "king" and then when we have "king" then it will print("this part has "king"")

Comment: Yeah, don't check for it being `None` because it could never possibly be `None`. Or pass `None` as the second argument to `.get`

Comment: How to pass it?

Comment: Here is my update

Comment: Please add a high-level explanation of what you are trying to accomplish with this code. It's not obvious what is the intended behavior beyond the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you just want to check if a 'king' exists in each sub dict in your list. In that case you can just directly check for that key.

```
a = [{"king":["man"],"man":"one"},{"man":"one"}]
for x in a:
    exists = x.get('king', [])
    if exists:
        print 'has'
    else:
        print 'None'
```

output:

```
has
None
```

---

**UPDATES —**

It seems like you just want to print king's attributes if a king exists. However, you only want to print it when king has a 'tok' attribute. The logic below should allow you to do that.

```
for x in a:
    king_attributes = x.get('king', [])
    if not king_attributes:
        print 'empty' # if no king available
        continue

    for attributes in king_attributes:
        if 'tok' not in attributes:
            print 'wrong'
        else:
            print attributes['tok']  # print the tok if we have it
```

Output:

```
many
empty
empty
sin
kingkong
```

Comment: That check can just be `if 'king' in x` (no need for exists).

Comment: I tried out your answer with another example as updated in my post but it wont work. Could you tell me why please

Comment: Added updates, let me know if I follow your logic. I'm not sure why you are printing wrong in your example. Based on your logic, it should be 'kingkong'. Am I right?

Comment: Wondering if this worked for ya. Let me know if you need me to clarify something.